# kwhtmltopdf: HTML table unexpected cell space in output PDF

Tags: html, wkhtmltopdf

I am testing wkhtmltopdf (0.13.0 alpha) to generate a pdf from a html table. 
But I am having an issue: in the middle of the table, the row gets a extra white space in the output PDF.

*Why is this happening and how to solve this?*

This is the command I used:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe -s A4 C:\Users\tonyv\Desktop\EX\tabela.html C:\temp\wkhtml4.pdf
Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)
Done
```

tabela.html:
[image: HTML]

wkhtml4.pdf:
[image: PDF]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>HTML Tables</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 10px
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
            table { page-break-inside:auto }
            tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
            thead { display:table-header-group }
            tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:aqua;background-color:black">Row 1, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:aqua;background-color:black"></td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:aqua;background-color:black">Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
            <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After I downgraded to the version to 0.12.4 (stable)

then it outputs/displays correctly on the PDF.

[image]